# AS3 dispatchEvent not working on class

Tags: actionscript-3, events, dispatchevent

i created this event class:

```
package com.site {
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class clientEvent extends Event {
        public static const connectionSucceeded: String = "connectionSucceeded";

        public var prams: Object;

        public function clientEvent(type: String, prams: Object) {
            super(type);
            this.prams = prams;
        }
        override public function clone(): Event {
            return new clientEvent(type, prams);
        }
    }
}
```

and on other class (Not main) im writed:

```
dispatchEvent(new clientEvent(clientEvent.connectionSucceeded, new Object()));
```

Im import the class and its return this error:
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method dispatchEvent.

Comment: Doe the class that does the dispatch also have an `import flash.events.Event;`? Or just try it like `import flash.events.*;`

Answer (score 1):

The other class should extend `EventDispatcher` class.

See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html